# Photo/Video recording app that collects and exports accelerometer/gyroscope sensor data

Tags: android, video-recording

Is there a photo/video recording app that also collects and exports the accelerometer/gyroscope and other such sensors' data?

The aim is to be able to, for example, use an external video editing software to perform video stabilization by using that sensor data - the same way some in-built camera software does in the phone itself.

I suppose the sensor data could be captured separately and simultaneously while recording the video, but it might not be easy to synchronize later.

Requirements:

- Takes picture or records video, as well as the current accelerometer/gyroscope sensor data

  - In case of picture, it should be able to capture in burst mode, or continuosly take pictures (with sensor data) as long as the user wants.
- Exports the picture and/or video with the sensor data
- Sensor data must be in an open format (not proprietary, even if the app itself is)

Nice to have:

- Ability to do both: record video and capture photo, but only one (photo) will do as well.

OS: Android

License: Any

Price: Any

Comment: Interesting question! Are you looking for gratis or paid, or does it not matter?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Thanks. Gratis/paid (is that classified as license?) - any, or doesn't matter.

Comment: You're welcome.  Licenses (and open or closed source, for that matter) can be independent of financial cost.  Put another way, some licenses have to be gratis, but others can charge.  Your edit makes it perfectly clear that you are open to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found one: https://gyroflow.xyz

It's a whole system to produce stabilized videos (which is what I wanted to do as well) but their app alone does what I wanted (export data), so double win